# ajax form submit for more than one values and get response

Tags: php, ajax

I am using a form and submitting a form having first name, last name, email, username as fields. when ajax returns back it return a string of error messages. how to separate that error messages?
i am using this code

$(document).ready(function () {


       $(":button[value=Done]").click(function () {
            data_first_name = $("#first_name").val();
            data_last_name = $("#last_name").val();
            data_user_name = $("#user_name").val();
            data_email = $("#email").val();
            data_role = $("#role").val();
            data_password = $("#password").val();
            data_profile_image = $("#upload_admin_image").val();

            $.post("process/process_add_user.php", {
                first_name: data_first_name,
                last_name: data_last_name,
                email: data_email,
                role: data_role,
                password: data_password,
                user_name: data_user_name,
                profile_image: data_profile_image
            },
            function (resp) {
                $("#first_name_error").html(resp);
            });

        });
    });

Comment: can you show the code and the error messages ??

Comment: Depends on how that string of error messages looks like, try providing some code and the approach you've taken...

Comment: _“when ajax returns back it return a string of error messages. how to separate that error messages?”_ – don’t have it return a simple _string_ in the first place, but a proper data structure, such as a JSON object that contains a mapping of fields and their errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [response code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). The code should be representative of the actual error(s) though.

> when ajax returns back it return a string of error messages. how to separate that error messages?

You can send the collection of error messages as a JSON string, and deal with those errors as necessary in your error handler function.

in the case of an error:

```
<?php
http_response_code(400);
// maps a form field to an error message.
$a = array('username' => 'no username', 'email' => 'no email');
echo json_encode($a);
```

In the normal case:

```
<?php
http_response_code(200);
echo "Success message";
```

This scheme works well with many ajax libraries when you can set event handlers for individual status codes or even just `success` and `fail` callbacks.

An example with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    400: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var errors = JSON.parse(errorThrown);
        if (errors.username) {
            $('#username-error').text(errors.username);
        }
    },
    200: function(data) {
        // ...
    }
  }
});
```

An example with vanilla JavaScript:

```
var handlers = {
   400: function (responseText) {
       var errors = JSON.parse(responseText);
       if (errors.username) {
           var name_error = document.querySelector('#username-error');
           name_error.textContent = errors.username;
       }
   },
   200: function (responseText) { /* ... */ }
};

function ajaxCall(url, handlers) {
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    r.open("POST", url, true);
    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (r.readyState === 4 && typeof handers[r.status] === 'function') {
            handers[r.status](r.responseText);
        }
    };
    r.send(/* ... */);
}

ajaxCall('userform_validation.php', handlers);
```

Comment: But i have more than one error messages. and i want to display in more than one divs. how i can handle it?

Answer (score 0):

To output an AJAX response as text on a webpage, first create a new `DIV` in your HTML

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

And use the following script to write the Ajax text response to the `DIV`. You will need to call it with a function.

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

More information on Ajax responses http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp

Comment: But i have more than one error messages. and i want to display in more than one divs. how i can handle it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the string? Is the response in XML format?